# Pylot MVC unable to locate the controller

Tags: python, model-view-controller

I created a controller in Pylot MVC and havent been able to figure out why it wont load the controller I created. I have it named appropriately. My controller is called courses.py, looks like so:

```
from system.core.model import Model
class Course(Controller):
 def __init__(self):
    super(Course, self).__init__()
 def index(self):
    return self.load_view('index')
```

My routes are set up and look right too

```
from system.core.router import routes
routes['default_controller'] = 'Courses'
```

I get this error when I try to run my server:

> ImportError: No module named Courses

Any ideas on where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: Is your file called `courses.py`, but you're trying to import `Courses`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with help from a friend. I had two problems. One I named the controller class wrong. Should of been Courses like so.

```
 from system.core.model import Model
 class Courses(Controller):
   def __init__(self):
     super(Courses, self).__init__()
   def index(self):
     return self.load_view('index')
```

The other issue for anyone else who gets this same error is that the controller file itself has to be capitalized. I named my controller file courses.py and it had to be Courses.py.